# What controller to use for a visualforce tab?

Tags: standardcontroller, tab

I have a VisualForce page that uses an Apex class to provide extensions, and this is what I have when I put that page on the Contact page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" showHeader="false" extensions="MyApexClass">
```

And then MyApexClass does this

```
public MyApexClass (ApexPages.StandardController sc){
```

But I want to create a page to put this on a custom tab. Is there a standard controller I can use? Is there a list of standard controllers somewhere (I haven't been able to find it yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a custom controller.  Set the `controller` attribute instead.

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
```

The constructor for a custom controller is a little simpler then the one used with an extension:

```
public MyController()
```

You wouldnt use a standardController here because a tab provides no sObject context.

Comment: Notably, this means that my extensions class needs to have a constructor that takes a MyController instance